# Bitbucket pipelines not using cache for bundle install

Tags: ruby, caching, bitbucket

I have tried every variation of naming my cache and nothing seems to work

My cache is being downloaded properly as I can see in the build setup.

```
Cache "bundler": Downloading
Cache "bundler": Downloaded 25.2 MiB in 1 seconds
Cache "bundler": Extracting
Cache "bundler": Extracted in 0 seconds
```

however when I go to `bundle install` I always get

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Installing rake 12.3.3
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Installing i18n 0.9.5
Installing minitest 5.11.3
Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
Installing activesupport 5.2.3
Installing builder 3.2.3
..........
```

Here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Run Tests
        image: ruby:2.6.4
        caches:
          - bundler
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs python-dev
          - bundle install --path ./vendor
          - cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
          - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:setup
          - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:schema:load
          - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec
        services:
          - postgres
          - redis

definitions:
  caches:
    bundler: ./vendor
  services:
    redis:
      image: redis
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: 'xxxxx'
        POSTGRES_USER: 'xxxxx'
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'xxxxx'
```

Comment: Bitbucket Pipelines has terrible documentation, and for my config, which is similar to OP's, I am not even getting the acknowlegdment that I have a cache configured, and nothing is being downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are solved you problem, the BitBucket Caches docs are out of date. So a solved my problem with this commands:

```yaml
- gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
- bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'
- bundle install
- bundle binstubs --all
```

My be, is needed remove `tzinfo-data` for linux deploy.

You can understand more reading the `bundle binstubs` [docs](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html).